# Pycharm reuse last opened console when running the script

Tags: python, pycharm

I recently switched from `Visual Studio Code` to `PyCharm` - just to try it out. I have a python project, it is a console application, so I often run it. The problem is when I run it - it opens a different `Python console` tab, which takes more time to load (it sets up paths etc.). So I end up with multiple tabs on the bottom of my screen, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to configure PyCharm so it will run my app in the same console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special option for this in PyCharm: **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console | Use existing console for "Run with Python console"**.